# Array of components doesn't update when props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-https-y8m26c?file=/src/App.js:0-42)

I have two components, a Parent and a Child. The Parent components keeps a list of Children in state and renders it using the map method.

The parent:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent(){
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const [childKey, setChildKey] = useState(0);
    const [children, setChildren] = useState([]);

    function addChild(){
        setChildren([...children, <Child counter={counter} index={childKey}/>]);
        setChildKey(childKey + 1);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h2>The parent component</h2>
            <p>The counter is set to {counter}</p>
            <p><button onClick={() => {setCounter(counter + 1)}}>Increment</button></p>
            <p><button onClick={addChild}>Add child</button></p>

            {children.map((c, i) => {
                return (
                        <div key={i}>{c}</div>
                    );
            })}
            
        </>
    );
}
```

The Child:

```
export default function Child({counter, index}){
    return (
        <>
            <p>Child {index}: the counter is set to {counter}</p>
        </>
    );
}
```

Clicking the "add child" button adds an child to the children array.

Clicking the "increment" button updates the counter on the parent, but the counter in the children does not change.

Is there a way to re-render the children when the counter increments?
(while preferably keeping the children in an array)

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-https-y8m26c?file=/src/App.js:0-42)

Comment: Keeping components in state doesn't seem like a good idea. Is there a reason you're doing it this way rather than just storing information that you can iterate over returning new child components for that information?

Comment: In a project i am working on, i have a form where you can add a section to the form, and it seemed like a good idea to store the sections components in an array. In my defense i am fairly new to React, and thanks to you and the answers I got, I understand that instead of storing components i should only store the data that makes the component in the state. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
setChildren([...children, <Child counter={counter} index={childKey}/>]);
```

Don't put elements into state. It makes it really easy to have bugs like the one you're having right now. You've effectively "locked in" what the props to the child are, so changes to the counter will not take effect.

Instead, just store the minimal data that's needed to create the elements, and then create those elements during rendering. In your case, i think you just need a number saying how many children to render. Conveniently, you already have that in `childKey`, so i recommend:

```
export default function Parent(){
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const [childKey, setChildKey] = useState(0);

    const children = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= childKey; i++) {
      children.push((
        <div key={i}>
          <Child counter={counter} index={i} />
        </div>
      ));
    }

    function addChild(){
        setChildKey(childKey + 1);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h2>The parent component</h2>
            <p>The counter is set to {counter}</p>
            <p><button onClick={() => {setCounter(counter + 1)}}>Increment</button></p>
            <p><button onClick={addChild}>Add child</button></p>

            {children}
            
        </>
    );
}
```

Maybe `childKey` could be renamed to `childCount`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```js
setChildren([...children, <Child counter={counter} index={childKey}/>]);
```

You tell React to add `<Child counter={counter} index={childKey}/>` element to the `children` state. It creates an element with the props `counter` and `childKey` with the values that they have at the time you add them to the state. Re-rendering these elements with a different value for `childKey` will have no impact.

Depending on what you want to do, there are many solutions. If you want to render `Child` with the value of `counter` at the time of re-render I would do something like this:

```js
export default function Parent(){
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const [childKey, setChildKey] = useState(0);
    const [children, setChildren] = useState([]);

    function addChild(){
        setChildren([...children, ({ counter }) => <Child counter={counter} index={childKey}/>]);
        setChildKey(childKey + 1);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h2>The parent component</h2>
            <p>The counter is set to {counter}</p>
            <p><button onClick={() => {setCounter(counter + 1)}}>Increment</button></p>
            <p><button onClick={addChild}>Add child</button></p>

            {children.map((childFn, i) => {
                return (
                        <div key={i}>{childFn({ counter })}</div>
                    );
            })}
            
        </>
    );
}
```

Or may be simpler (and less error prone):

```js
export default function Parent(){
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const [childKey, setChildKey] = useState(0);
    const [children, setChildren] = useState([]);

    function addChild(){
        setChildren([...children, childKey]);
        setChildKey(childKey + 1);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h2>The parent component</h2>
            <p>The counter is set to {counter}</p>
            <p><button onClick={() => {setCounter(counter + 1)}}>Increment</button></p>
            <p><button onClick={addChild}>Add child</button></p>

            {children.map((childKey, i) => {
                return (
                        <div key={i}><Child counter={counter} index={childKey} /></div>
                    );
            })}
            
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes like other answers keeping components in state is not a good idea - well explained by *Nicholas* above

Same answer but different style of `rendering`

Just updated the `Parent.js` as below

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [childKey, setChildKey] = useState(0);

  function addChild() {
    setChildKey(childKey + 1);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>The parent component</h2>
      <p>The counter is set to {counter}</p>
      <p>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setCounter(counter + 1);
          }}
        >
          Increment
        </button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button onClick={addChild}>Add child</button>
      </p>
      {/* create an array of length of childKey number */}
      {Array.from({ length: childKey }, (_, i) => {
        return <Child key={i} counter={counter} index={i} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```